# Using select method in SQL

Tags: android, sql, date

I've added 3 strings of data into a SQL database in android. A fourth string makes up the database, however it is a date:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd)

Date outputDate = new Date();
```

When the user enters information to the database, the adding method for the database creates the date, which is added to the database.

My question is, how can I use these imported dates to create a method whereby only the rows in the database that were added on in the last 31 days?

A SELECT method comes to mind through research, but I don't know how to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you ask about Android I assume that the database you use is SQLite. SQLite does not have datatype for date. Thus you have couple of options: store the date in string (like you did) or store the timestamp of the date.

I seriously recommend you to use the second option as it is going to convert your dates in integers and it will be even easier to handle.

Thus when you want to select only events in the last 31 days you can do:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWriteableDatabase();
final long millisIn31Days = 31 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
String where = "<your-date-column> >= ?"
String [] whereArgs = { String.valueOf(new Date().getTime() - millisIn31Days) };
Cursor cursor =
    database.query("<TABLE_NAME>", null, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

Note that here I write in angular brackets all the values you should actually fill in with the correct constants.

If you, however, want to stick to the string solution, you can still go with string comparison, as long as you specify the date format in correct manner (yours seems to be like that). In the string solution you will need to calculate the date of 31 days ago. You can use the `Calendar`'s class auxiliary methods to achieve that.

Comment: Where in the Database class should this code be: i.e. under the method created to output?

Comment: Thankyou so much! I adapted the code, instead getting long values for the date inputted and the date when the code was to be outputted, then a simple boolean subtraction to compare the code!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your database engine is SQLite, you should try something like that

```
SELECT * from your_table where julianday('now') - julianday(your_date_field)<=31;
```

You may be interested in SQLite date functions as well: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Apologies, what is meant by "(your_date_field) ?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about the database field containing the date introduced when the statement was created... I am missing something?

Comment: No I do apologies, while when I crack something and write my own code I'm okay, but interpreting other peoples code is my very week point!

I decided to move away from this SELECT * method, with help from the other reply I managed to crack it! Thankyou though!